# ESD plug in with battery backup UPS

Tags: ground, esd

Is plunging in an ESD strap to a batter backup like a UPS or APC reasonable? I have a simple ESD cable that terminated in a 3 prong wall outlet where only the earth ground prong is metal. There is a 1MEG ohm resistor between the contact on the strap and the earth ground prong. Will the strap discharge me to earth ground through the backup? Is there a way to tell if power strips are isolated from earth ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your UPS is still connected to the mains, even if it's a blackout or not, still physically connected, yes and yes. Measure from your other hand to ground. You should see just over 1 Mohm of resistance.